# Convert Dataset to IQueryable<T> or IEnumerable<T>

Tags: linq, datatable, ienumerable, iqueryable

Since there is no Linq to DB2 yet (c'mon IBM!), and I want to deal with IQueryables or IEnumerables in my code, how would I convert a DataTable to an IQueryable? Or an IEnumerable?

I have an interface and a class that matches the columns in the datatable...

```
IQueryable<IMyData> GetAS400Data(..parameters..)
{
    DataSet d = GetData();
    ...
    //Some code to convert d to IQueryable<IMyData>
}
```

DataTable.Rows does not support .AsQueryable, since MSFT yanked it, so I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: .AsEnumerable() <= using System.Data;

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
table.AsEnumerable()...

table.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()...
```

However, you'd need to write your own translation (`Select`) to your type; and the `IQueryable<T>` would still be using LINQ-to-Objects; the only purpose (in this scenario) of using `IQueryable<T>` over `IEnumerable<T>` would be to use expressions for some other reason - perhaps for the [dynamic LINQ library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Comment: How do you convert the other way? From IQueryable to a DataTable?

Comment: The `IQueryable<T>` is essentially a view over the data. The original `DataTable` still remains. To *create* a `DataTable`, perhaps see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545328/datatable-to-generic-list-memory-leak

Comment: @MarcGravell could elaborate please on how to do the translation ? i tried IQueryable<T> resultList =(DataSet.Tables[0]).AsEnumerable().AsQueryable(); i got an error: can not convert type IQueryable<DataRow> to type IQueryable<T>.

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this.

```
DataSet ds = GetData();
DataTable dt= ds.Tables[0];
var query =
    from row in dt.AsEnumerable() 
    select new IMyData()
    {
        property1= row[0],
        property2= row[1]
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look here](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/01/26/entity-framework-enabled-providers-lists.aspx) it seems that a provider with entity framework for DB2 exists.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to a bad experience last year, EF has been ruled out for me. That's unfortunate, since EF is MSFT's future...

Comment: Change job then :)