# Reflection - getting properties of nested objects

Tags: c#, reflection, propertyinfo, getproperties

refers to : [Reflection - setting Type of returned obj?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906327/reflection-setting-type-of-returned-obj)
I have a object Call Jobcard with a few properties, one of which is another object called Customer with its own properties, one of which is another nested object called Adress.

These 2  functions will be handling other object types as well.

```
private T PopulateObject<T>(T dataObj, System.Data.DataRow dataRow)
{

    //Type type = dataObj.GetType();
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] proplist = dataObj.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach ( System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyitem in proplist)
    {
        if(propertyitem.Name != "")
        //s += propertyitem.Name + ":" + (propertyitem.GetValue(dataObj,null)).ToString() + "\r\n";
            try
            {
                propertyitem.SetValue(dataObj, dataRow[propertyitem.Name], null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message.Contains("does not belong to table"))
                {
                   propertyitem.SetValue(dataObj, PopulateChildObject(propertyitem, dataRow), null);
                }
                else
                throw;
            } 
    }
    return dataObj;
}



private object PopulateChildObject(object dataObj, System.Data.DataRow dataRow)
{

    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] proplist = dataObj.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach ( System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyitem in proplist)
    {
        if(propertyitem.Name != "")
            try
            {
                propertyitem.SetValue(dataObj, dataRow[propertyitem.Name], null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {           
             if (ex.Message.Contains("does not belong to table"))
                {
                   propertyitem.SetValue(dataObj, PopulateChildObject(propertyitem, dataRow), null);
                }
                else
                throw;
            } 
    }
    return dataObj;
}
```

The problem is that the PopulateChildObject function does not work because the PropertyInfo list is not that of the passed childObj.
If I look at the dataObj passed to PopulateChildObject in the watch, it has 0 Attributes. Also the dataObj passed to PopChildObj() has type of System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' instead of type Customer. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`propertyitem` is the `PropertyInfo`; you need to pass it the *value* from the property - i.e.

```
propertyItem.GetValue(dataObj, null);
```

If this child object is created by the parent, you shouldn't need to "set" it; just update the underyling object:

```
PopulateChildObject(propertyitem.GetValue(dataObj, null), dataRow);
```

It may be you need to *create* the child object (usually `Activator.CreateInstance`), in which case you *will* need to call `SetValue`:

```
object child = propertyitem.GetValue(dataObj, null);
if(child == null) {
    child = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyitem.PropertyType);
    propertyitem.SetValue(dataObj, child, null);
}
PopulateChildObject(child, dataRow);
```

I wonder, though - is there really any difference between `PopulateObject` and `PopulateChildObject`? It feels like they could be the same thing?

Comment: difference between PopulateObject and PopulateChildObject:
I could not get a recursive call to PopulateObject working because the type of childobject has to be passed as well.

Comment: Only because you made it generic - but (as per my reply on the previous question) there is little benefit in the generics here.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I got It wotking with help from another post by you: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=30043135&threadid=30043131

propertyitem.PropertyType;

is what I needed to do

Answer (score 0):

Get Nest properties e.g., Developer.Project.Name

```
private static System.Reflection.PropertyInfo GetProperty(object t, string PropertName)
            {
                if (t.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == PropertName.Split('.')[0]) == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(string.Format("Property {0}, is not exists in object {1}", PropertName, t.ToString()));
                if (PropertName.Split('.').Length == 1)
                    return t.GetType().GetProperty(PropertName);
                else
                    return GetProperty(t.GetType().GetProperty(PropertName.Split('.')[0]).GetValue(t, null), PropertName.Split('.')[1]);
            }
```