# C# convert dataset to generic list of multiple entities

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, oracle11g

> EDIT: I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/545429/2025443) answer, and was curious if I can do something
>   similar.

My project have a data layer which communicate with the database only by stored procedures. One of the procedures returns data from two tables, which has one to many relationship. I'm using the OracleDataAdapter from Oracle Data Access library. The Adapter fills a DataTable. I have a entity class A that has a List of another entity class B. I need to convert the DataTable to match this relationship. The Datatable will be filled with multiple rows that has only different B objects. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

EDIT2: Let's say I have 2 classes, A and B.

```
public class A{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
public class B{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a DataTable with data like:

```
Id    Nome    Descricao      Data        Quantidade    Id_B     Nome_B
1    "nome1"   "desc1"    05/07/2013         2          5      "nomeB_1"
1    "nome1"   "desc1"    05/07/2013         2          13     "nomeB_2"
```

So, A can have multiple B objects. I want to make a generic parser, that can take this DataTable and convert it to a List of B within a List of A. I think its possible to use Marc Gravell's solution with some recursive method that analises the property for know if is a List, and process it for each duplicated Id in A. Anyone know if this is possible?

Thank you in advance, and I apologize for the bad english.

Comment: Have you tried a standard LINQ join?

Comment: @GarryVass Garry, can you show me how? Let's say I have a datatable row with A_Id, A_Name, A_Description, A_Date, B_Id, B_Name. My A table has int Id, string Name, string Description and List<A> B, and my B table has int Id and string Name. How can I do this?