# very slow reading of txt file using File.ReadLines in c#

Tags: c#, file, readlines

I read the file line by line and insert this data to DB using entity framework. The reading is very slow. The file is almost 6 millions of rows and I need encrease the perfomance of reading of the file. It is a dictionary of words in this file and I need to insert these words in database table. Below are several lines of that file.

```
390201
ТАТАМИ  NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd sing,nomn
ТАТАМИ  NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd sing,gent
ТАТАМИ  NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd sing,datv
ТАТАМИ  NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd sing,accs
ТАТАМИ  NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd sing,ablt
ТАsing,gent
ОРИГАМИ NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd ТАМИ    NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd sing,loct
ТАТАМИ  NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd plur,nomn
ТАТАМИ  NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd plur,gent
ТАТАМИ  NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd plur,datv
ТАТАМИ  NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd plur,accs
ТАТАМИ  NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd plur,ablt
ТАТАМИ  NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd plur,loct

390202
ОРИГАМИ NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd sing,nomn
ОРИГАМИ NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd sing,datv
ОРИГАМИ NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd sing,accs
ОРИГАМИ NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd sing,ablt
ОРИГАМИ NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd sing,loct
ОРИГАМИ NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd plur,nomn
ОРИГАМИ NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd plur,gent
ОРИГАМИ NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd plur,datv
ОРИГАМИ NOUN,inan,neut,Fixd plur,accs
```

My code for parsing of that file is below:

```
public static void parseFileFromToSegment(int beginId, int endId)
    {
    using (var db = new Context())
    {
        string theWordFromFile;
        string wordData;
        int wordIdFromFile = 1;
        int tempWordId;

        IEnumerable<string> allFileLines = File.ReadLines(fileName);
        allFileLines = allFileLines.SkipWhile(n => n != beginId.ToString());
        foreach (string line in allFileLines)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                continue;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && Int32.TryParse(line, out tempWordId))
            {
                if (tempWordId < beginId)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (tempWordId > endId) 
                    break;

                wordIdFromFile = tempWordId;
                if (wordIdFromFile % 100 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Current id - " + wordIdFromFile);
                continue;
            }

            theWordFromFile = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf('\t'));
            wordData = line.Substring(line.IndexOf('\t')).Trim();
            TheWord theWord = new TheWord { WordFormId = wordIdFromFile, word = theWordFromFile, word_form_data = wordData };

            db.TheWords.Add(theWord);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        Console.WriteLine("saved");
    }
}
```

So the speed of reading is very slow. What can I do to improve performance? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the slow performance doesn't come from adding 6 million records to EF in a single `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: @SimonKarlsson He is already doing it. `File.ReadLines` returns a `IEnumerable<string>` and underneath uses `StreamReader.ReadLine()`

Comment: This piece `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) &&` is useless. You already checked the opposite the line before. But it won't change the speed

Comment: Try calling `SaveChanges()` inside the loop - but not for every iteration, of course. You can save each 1000 rows

Comment: @DenisItskovich although that'd help, if performance is what I'm looking after, I'd just not use EF at all for a 6 million row bulk-insert operation

Comment: Why do you think the *reading* is the bottleneck? Did you profile the code? What does "too slow" mean anyway? Does it take 200ms? 10 seconds? 10 minutes? How does the table you're inserting into look? What DB engine are you using? Also, you can't "seek" in a text file, so finding the `beginId` always means reading every single character preceding that `beginId` - depending on your usage of the method, this can result in a fairly typical Schlemiel.

Comment: save changes is not a problem. It works fast. Reading the file takes many hours.

Comment: @AlexeyRumin Maybe `db.TheWords.Add(theWord);` is causing the problem, everytime you call that, EF calls `DetectChanges`. Can you try adding `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; ` right after you create the context?

Comment: @Alexander Derck  You are right, thank you. I created a List for "theWord" objects and used List.AddRange(list with theWord objects) methd - the probleb is solved - it was in detecting changes of EF.

Comment: @AlexeyRumin You're welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the file reads that are slow. It's the DB inserts.

You could use pure ADO.NET with a `DataAdapter` to insert the rows ([using batching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2(v=vs.110).aspx)) or the `SQLBulkCopy` class ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841000/sql-bulk-copy-insert-in-c-sharp)).

Comment: savechanges is not the problem - the saving will be done in this method after 20 000 lines are read. But the reading of them is very very small. And when they are read EF works fine - saves them very fast

Comment: It's easy to test that. Simply comment out all Entity Framework code and run the sample again. Is it fast?

Comment: I commented - it still works very slow. It will take many hours (20-30) to read the entire file

Comment: Was that without the database code? I don't care about `SaveChanges()`. Did you test it without ALL database code? Because it's unlikely that a DB insert is faster than a file read unless the file is read over a very slow network share.

Comment: you were right - the problem was in EF. As Alexander Derck  told in comment - "Maybe db.TheWords.Add(theWord); is causing the problem, everytime you call that, EF calls DetectChanges." I added a list for adding the "theWord" objects and used method AddRange for adding objects. After that saved shanges. Works perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AlexeyRumin that's also not your only problem, it's absurd to open the file and read all previous lines just to skip ahead... open the file outside your function and don't reopen it on every batch iteration

Comment: @Jcl Before it I tried to solve the problem using multithreading - each thread had to open the file and parse from defenite line. So I just didn't deleted. Before it I opened file only once. Thanky for writing about this problem in code

Comment: @AlexeyRumin as a future advice:  I/O-bound processes on the same file (actually, on the same physical disk) *never* get better with multithreading. CPU-bound processes might.

Comment: @Jcl  Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 3):

Reading all the comments, it seems you are calling `parseFileFromToSegment` every 20.000 "ids", which are probably (according to your sample text) many lines for each id.

So you are calling your `parseFileFromToSegment` and doing this:

```
IEnumerable<string> allFileLines = File.ReadLines(fileName);
allFileLines = allFileLines.SkipWhile(n => n != beginId.ToString());
```

On every call: that reads from the start, potentially millions of already read lines in the file every time you call it.

Try to make that call just one time and see if it's faster, and if you want to batch-save every 'n' records, then do so, don't open and read [potentially] the whole file every single iteration of 'n'