# Bulk INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE in one transaction

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, dapper

I'm trying to do a bulk 'sync' (insert, update and delete) into a database in C# .NET. I'm using Dapper because Entity Framework is not suited for the project for other reasons. There are a couple of requirements that make my question extra difficult:

- Again, the solution cannot use Entity Framework.
- The entire 'sync' must be one transaction.
- The sql must be generated dynamically as the DTO's that need to be synced are one-to-one copies of tables in the database. IE: table `Course` matches to a .NET DTO `Course` with certain properties that also exist as columns in the database.
- The solution must (obviously) be safe against SQL Injection attacks.

How the solution works right now:

- A different class calls a `repository.sync()` method to 'sync' all DTO's for a single customer.
- That customer has it's own schema in the database. The name of the schema is supplied to the repository upon the sync call.
- The sync call has a param entitiesToSync of type `Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Synchronizable, TransactionType>>` where

  - Synchronizable is the DTO to synchronize
  - TransactionType is an enum with values `{Added, Updated, Deleted}`
  - The Type is the type of the DTO to synchronize, which also equates to the name of the table of that DTO.
- Upon calling the sync method, the entitiesToSync are split into three new dictionaries based on the TransactionType (added, updated, deleted).

What I'm struggling with:

- For the added entities an INSERT sql statement should be generated.
- For each of the updated entities a separate UPDATE sql statement should be generated.
- For the deleted entities a DELETE sql statement should be generated.
- All of these statements must be executed within one transaction in a safe way, to prevent SQL Injection.

The reason I find this difficult is that in order to safely generate SQL statements, parameters need to be used. Using reflection I can see the properties that the DTO has and generate the statements. The issue is that the number of entities can be quite big and using unique parameters for every single item could lead to huge DynamicParameter objects. I believe there is a limit to the number of parameter SQL Server supports. The solution is to execute the statements in parts, but that is impossible as the sync should be one transaction.

Also, to keep the solution from using enormous amounts of resources I would like to generate as little statements and parameters as possible. I think I could use temp tables to do this, but I'm not sure how because I would also need to dynamically generate those temp tables and insert things into them which might be exactly the same as directly inserting into the actual table.

**TLDR**; How can one perform one transaction to bulk insert, update and delete thousands of records AND how can code to do this be generated from PropertyInfo of .NET type?

Comment: The question is unclear because you can write any UPDATE or DELETE statement you want with Dapper, and `BULK INSERT` has special meaning, only loading files, using minimal logging. There's no `BULK UPDATE` or `BULK DELETE`, the operations are fully logged. You can easily use Dapper to execute `DELETE MyTable WHERE Category=@category`

Comment: Perhaps you're imposing an artificial limitation on yourself - a single transaction can span as many statements as you like.

Comment: The issue is not that I am unable to write UPDATE or DELETE statements with Dapper, but that there can be thousands of records that need to be inserted, updated and deleted at once within a single transaction.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I am aware. The intention is to use multiple statements in one transaction. The issue is that there can be so many parameters in this one transaction that the limit of around 2100 (I think) might be too low.

Comment: Parameters don't apply to transactions, they apply to statements. Yes, there is a limit of 2100 parameters on a single statement, but you can use as many statements as you like in a single transaction.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, 2100 parameter limit per batch. It's a longstanding TDS protocol limit.

Comment: Is there a limit to the size of a parameter? Otherwise I could build a SP and use one parameter for all of the statements and use separators to distinguish to which statement that data belongs: @CourseName='someName;someOtherName;AnotherName'?

Comment: Why not use a DataTable or bulk insert, put the data into a staging table together with a INSERTED/UPDATED/DELETED flag, and then run some generic procedure that builds a MERGE of the added data and your destination table. No need for dappers or EF

Comment: @siggemannen could you write an answer with a more detailed explanation of how to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you need a Table Valued Parameter somewhere, but it's hard to understand exactly what you are doing without seeing code.

Comment: @Charlieface I understand, but there is just way to much domain specific code to explain. The Table Valued Parameter is something I don't understand very well. I think I would need to define the TVP first, then fill it with basically entire DTO's, then use each record in the TVP once for every statement. 

The issue is that defining the TVP would also need to be generated, which is possible but would add more complexity. Also, aren't there limits on the amount of records you can put in a TVP? I will certainly look into it though. Thanks.

Comment: There are no limits on the size of a TVP, it's just the same as a table variable. Yes you need to define the TVP upfront. You can do a joined `UPDATE` or `MERGE` statement, rather than doing it cursor-like. A temp table is another option: create a temp table, load it using `SqlBulkCopy` then do a joined `UPDATE` from it.

Comment: You can do that with [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/) with ease, it has everything for such task `bulkcopy`, `merge`, `temporary tables`.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would handle generic entity sync is something like this:

1. Create a mirror staging table for your tables, i.e. Course => CourseStaging.
   The table can have same columns as target, but NULLable, together with a flag column that says what to do with the entity, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
2. When you sync your entities, figure out which staging table they belong to and use SQLBulkCopy that populates the staging table. You still need to be able to map a property to a field as well as datatype, but I'm guessing this code is already available for you. You can also use Dapper Ii guess to populate the staging table. This is much simpler, since there's no UPDATE / DELETEs here, only simple INSERT
3. Finally, you call some Procedure that does builds a MERGE statement that looks something like:

```sql
MERGE {TARGET} t
USING {SOURCE_STAGE} s
 ON s.{ID} = t.{ID}
WHEN MATCHED AND s.flag = 'insert' THEN INSERT (
 {COLUMNS}) VALUES({s.columns})
WHEN MATCHED AND s.flag = 'update' THEN UPDATE
SET {COLUMN_1} = s.{COLUMN_1}
...
WHEN MATCHED AND s.flag = 'delete' THEN DELETE
```

You need to generate the stuff dynamically, but it shouldn't be too hard, you can always look up the columns in `sys.columns`.

The merge can be ran in an explicit transaction, and in the end you have a fully updated target table.

Comment: This is perfect. I think I will use an edited version of your suggested answer; I will write the SP dynamically so the dto type can be passed along. As you say, the column names are available via sys.columns, so based on a param I can look up the correct columns, and perform the sync dynamically, resulting in just one SP. That way I won't have to generate a SP for every type of Dto (IE SyncCourse), but just build one SP SyncEntity(table t)

Comment: How can I insert the entities and flags at once instead of row-by-agonizing-row? I've read about SqlBulkCopy but don't understand how to implement this here

Comment: Read some stuff here perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841000/sql-bulk-copy-insert-in-c-sharp