# dataset to IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, dataset, iqueryable

i found the link
[DataSet to IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505054/convert-dataset-to-iqueryablet-or-ienumerablet)

but as i implemented:

```
 public IQueryable<ORDRE> Get_Ordre_ParDate_Iquery(string sql_SelectAll, DateTime dateDeb, DateTime dateFin)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connectionWrapper = new Connexion())
                {
                    var connectedConnection = connectionWrapper.GetConnected();

                    SqlCommand comm_SelectAll = new SqlCommand(sql_SelectAll, connectionWrapper.conn);

                    comm_SelectAll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE_CREE_DEB", dateDeb);
                    comm_SelectAll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE_CREE_FIN", dateFin);
                    SqlDataAdapter adapt_SelectAll = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    adapt_SelectAll.SelectCommand = comm_SelectAll;
                    DataSet dSet_SelectAll = new DataSet();
                    adapt_SelectAll.Fill(dSet_SelectAll, "LeOrdre");
                    dSet_SelectAll.Dispose();
                    adapt_SelectAll.Dispose();
                    return dSet_SelectAll.Tables["LeOrdre"].AsEnumerable().AsQueryable<ORDRE>();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception excThrown)
            {
                throw new Exception(excThrown.Message);
            }

        }
```

dSet_SelectAll.Tables["LeOrdre"].AsEnumerable().AsQueryable();
this line is not correct

Comment: What us `ORDRE` and how does it relate to this question? The `AsEnumerable()` here - won't that just be `IEnumerable<DataRow>`? How did you envisage that mapping to `ORDRE` ?

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like you're trying to get data from a TSQL command into instances of an object of type `ORDRE`. The `DataSet` and `DataAdapter` seems to just be the mechanism for processing the command and results; if that is the case, then it is pure overhead and isn't helping. I wonder if ["dapper"](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper) might be an easier option here, i.e.

```
public List<ORDRE> Get_Ordre_ParDate_Iquery(string sql_SelectAll,
    DateTime dateDeb, DateTime dateFin)
{
    using (var connectionWrapper = new Connexion())
    {
        connectionWrapper.GetConnected();
        return connectionWrapper.conn.Query<ORDRE>(sql_SelectAll,
            new { DATE_CREE_DEB = dateDeb, DATE_CREE_FIN = dateFin }).ToList()
    }
}
```

here the `Query<T>` method is from "dapper" and proves the command and result functionaltiy; the `new {...}` provides the parameters. The `ToList()` iterates the results into a `List<ORDRE>`. There is no benefit using `IQueryable<T>` here since that data **won't be composable**; however, if the caller understands that, they could use `.AsQueryable()` on the result if they want. But it will still be LINQ-to-Objects fundamentally (just wrapped in an `IQuerayble<T>` facade).